# Need to change my code into a loop (fill data to HTML with VBA)

Tags: vba, excel, loops, automation

This is the code I have right now. It works for a single run but I would like to know how to change the process into a loop.

```
Sub SearchBot()

    Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
    'Dim caseNumber As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim outputa As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim outputb As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim outputc As HTMLLinkElement
    Dim y As Integer
    'Dim outputa As String, outputb As String, outputc As String

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer

    objIE.Visible = True

    objIE.navigate "https://debbiezhou.github.io/citi-demo/addaddadd.html"

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


    objIE.document.getElementById("fullName").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A2").Value
    objIE.document.getElementById("nation").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    objIE.document.getElementById("DOB").Value = _
      Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C2").Value

    objIE.document.getElementById("submit").Click

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    y = 2

    For Each outputa In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("outName")
    For Each outputb In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("outNation")
    For Each outputc In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("outDob")

    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("E" & y).Value = outputa.innerText
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("F" & y).Value = outputb.innerText
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & y).Value = outputc.innerText

    Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    Debug.Print outputa.innerText
    Debug.Print outputb.innerText
    Debug.Print outputc.innerText
    Next
    Next
    Next
    objIE.Quit
End Sub
```

The way I'm using this right now is to assign every cell, but I need to deal with a lot of data, so I need it to be a loop or an array.

Answer (score 0):

You set y = 2 but don't increment it within your loops
try

```
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("G" & y).Value = outputc.innerText
y=y+1
Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop


 objIE.document.getElementById("fullName").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
objIE.document.getElementById("nation").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
objIE.document.getElementById("DOB").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you kindly help, I tried but then I figure out my problem is not only on the y part. what I really wants is to increase the value of "i" after everytime I printed the result. Is there any way to do so? Thank you so much!!!

Comment: the code is like following：

 objIE.document.getElementById("fullName").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A" & i).Value
objIE.document.getElementById("nation").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B" & i).Value
objIE.document.getElementById("DOB").Value = _
  Sheets("Sheet2").Range("C" & i).Value

Comment: just use 
     i = i +1
at the end of the block that prints the results and before the loop